# Why is the lossy conversion warning inconsistent?

Tags: java

The code below shows an error due to lossy conversion because math.pow returns a double, and I store the answer in an integer.

```
int k = 0
k = k + Math.pow(2, 4);
System.out.println(k);
```

but this code:

```
int k = 0
k += Math.pow(2, 4);
System.out.println(k);
```

Shows no error, why?

My question is: Why is there no error in the second code?

Comment: This is very interesting. 

Maybe there is an implicit cast

so -> `i += d` <==> `i = i + (int)d`
https://godbolt.org/z/1rbohf7Ts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Here, `+=` does `implicit cast`, where as `+` operator requires
> `explicit cast` for second operand, otherwise it won’t compile.

So in the first code, we are assigning the right side part `(k + Math.pow(2,4))` which becomes `double` after additon and assigning it to an `int` type variable at last. And that's an issue of **lossy conversion**.

If we explain the second code snippet,

```
int k = 0
k += Math.pow(2, 4);
System.out.println(k);
```

as per the java documentation we can see it's internal working like this:

```
int k = 0
k = (int) (k + Math.pow(2, 4));
System.out.println(k);
```

You can see in the doc [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26.2).